# how to make onPerformSync on Android syncadapter when network is available and content provider data changes?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

While implementing the android developers tutorial on sync adapters, http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html  i ended up with the following code on my activity:

**Activity.java**

```
// Constants
    // The authority for the sync adapter's content provider
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "sync.adapter.datacontentprovider";
    // An account type, in the form of a domain name
    public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.udinic.sync_example";
    // The account name
    public static final String ACCOUNT = "Udinic";
    // Instance fields
    Account mAccount;
    // Global variables
    // A content resolver for accessing the provider
    ContentResolver mResolver;
```

Inside onCreate(){

```
    mAccount = CreateSyncAccount(this);
// Get the content resolver for your app
mResolver = getContentResolver();
// Turn on automatic syncing for the default account and authority
mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, AUTHORITY, true);
```

method CreateSyncAccount:

```
public static Account CreateSyncAccount(Context context) {
            // Create the account type and default account
            Account newAccount = new Account(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            // Get an instance of the Android account manager
            AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context
                    .getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
            /*
             * Add the account and account type, no password or user data If
             * successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
             */
            if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null)) {
                /*
                 * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in in your <provider>
                 * element in the manifest, then call context.setIsSyncable(account,
                 * AUTHORITY, 1) here.
                 */
            } else {
                /*
                 * The account exists or some other error occurred. Log this, report
                 * it, or handle it internally.
                 */
                Log.d("insitu", "creating sync account error");
            }
            return newAccount;
        }
```

This is the standard way in android developers tutorials in sync adapters to run a sync adapter when an available connection is up.

Although i want this i also want it to only happen when there is new data in the ContentProvider i implemented.

```
public class datacontentprovider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String TAG = "DataContentProvider";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // table names
    private static final String LOCATION_TABLE_NAME = "location";
    private static final String PICTURE_TABLE_NAME = "picture";
    private static final String ACCELEROMETER_TABLE_NAME = "accelerometer";
    private static final String SOUND_TABLE_NAME = "sound";
    private static final String BATTERY_TABLE_NAME = "battery";
    private static final String ORIENTATION_TABLE_NAME = "orientation";
    private static final String LIGHT_TABLE_NAME = "light";

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "sync.adapter.datacontentprovider";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_LOCATION = Uri.parse("content://"
            + AUTHORITY + "/location");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_PICTURE = Uri.parse("content://"
            + AUTHORITY + "/picture");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_ACCELEROMETER = Uri.parse("content://"
            + AUTHORITY + "/accelerometer");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_SOUND = Uri.parse("content://"
            + AUTHORITY + "/sound");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_BATTERY = Uri.parse("content://"
            + AUTHORITY + "/battery");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_ORIENTATION = Uri.parse("content://"
            + AUTHORITY + "/orientation");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_LIGHT = Uri.parse("content://"
            + AUTHORITY + "/light");

    /*public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.jwei512.notes";
    public static final String NOTE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TEXT = "text";*/

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;

    private static final int LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int LOCATION_ID = 2;
    private static final int PICTURE = 3;
    private static final int PICTURE_ID = 4;
    private static final int ACCELEROMETER = 5;
    private static final int ACCELEROMETER_ID = 6;
    private static final int SOUND = 7;
    private static final int SOUND_ID = 8;
    private static final int BATTERY = 9;
    private static final int BATTERY_ID = 10;
    private static final int ORIENTATION = 11;
    private static final int ORIENTATION_ID = 12;
    private static final int LIGHT = 13;
    private static final int LIGHT_ID = 14;

    static {
        sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, LOCATION_TABLE_NAME, LOCATION);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, LOCATION_TABLE_NAME + "/#", LOCATION_ID);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PICTURE_TABLE_NAME, PICTURE);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PICTURE_TABLE_NAME + "/#", PICTURE_ID);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, ACCELEROMETER_TABLE_NAME, ACCELEROMETER);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, ACCELEROMETER_TABLE_NAME + "/#",
                ACCELEROMETER_ID);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SOUND_TABLE_NAME, SOUND);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SOUND_TABLE_NAME + "/#", SOUND_ID);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BATTERY_TABLE_NAME, BATTERY);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BATTERY_TABLE_NAME + "/#", BATTERY_ID);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, ORIENTATION_TABLE_NAME, ORIENTATION);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, ORIENTATION_TABLE_NAME + "/#",
                ORIENTATION_ID);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, LIGHT_TABLE_NAME, LIGHT);
        sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, LIGHT_TABLE_NAME + "/#", LIGHT_ID);

    }

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        /**
         * table for locations | _id | _latitude | _longitude | _time |
         * _provider
         */
        public static final String TABLE_LOCATION = "location";
        public static final String COLUMN_LOCID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "_latitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "_longitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "_time";
        public static final String COLUMN_ACCURACY = "_accuracy";
        public static final String COLUMN_PROVIDER = "_provider";

        /**
         * table for pictures | _id | _url | _latitude | _longitude | _time
         */
        public static final String TABLE_PICTURE = "picture";
        public static final String COLUMN_PIC_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_PIC_URL = "_url";
        public static final String COLUMN_PIC_LATITUDE = "_latitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_PIC_LONGITUDE = "_longitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_PIC_TIME = "_time";
        public static final String COLUMN_PIC_ACCURACY = "_accuracy";

        /**
         * table for Accelerometer | _id | _x | _y | _z | _time
         */
        public static final String TABLE_ACCELEROMETER = "accelerometer";
        public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_X = "_x";
        public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Y = "_y";
        public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Z = "_z";
        public static final String COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_TIME = "_time";

        /**
         * table for Sound | _id | _amplitude | _time
         */
        public static final String TABLE_AMPLITUDE = "sound";
        public static final String COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_AMPLITUDE = "_amplitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_TIME = "_time";

        /**
         * table for Battery | _id | _status | _ischarging | _chargeplug |
         * _usbcharge | _accharge | _level | _scale | _batterypct | _time
         */
        public static final String TABLE_BATTERY = "battery";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_STATUS = "_status";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_ISCHARGING = "_ischarging";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_CHARGEPLUG = "_chargeplug";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_USBCHARGE = "_usbcharge";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_ACCHARGE = "_accharge";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_LEVEL = "_level";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_SCALE = "_scale";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_BATTERYPCT = "_batterypct";
        public static final String COLUMN_BATTERY_TIME = "_time";

        /**
         * table for Orientation | _id | _azimut | _time
         */
        public static final String TABLE_ORIENTATION = "orientation";
        public static final String COLUMN_ORIENTATION_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_ORIENTATION_AZIMUT = "_azimut";
        public static final String COLUMN_ORIENTATION_TIME = "_time";

        /**
         * table for Light | _id | _luminosity | _time
         */
        public static final String TABLE_LIGHT = "light";
        public static final String COLUMN_LIGHT_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_LIGHT_LUMINOSITY = "_luminosity";
        public static final String COLUMN_LIGHT_TIME = "_time";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "memory.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database creation sql statement for location
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_LOC = "create table "
                + TABLE_LOCATION + "(" + COLUMN_LOCID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_LATITUDE
                + " double not null, " + COLUMN_LONGITUDE
                + " double not null, " + COLUMN_TIME + " text not null, "
                + COLUMN_ACCURACY + " text not null, " + COLUMN_PROVIDER
                + " text not null " + ");";

        // Database creation sql statement for picture
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_PIC = "create table "
                + TABLE_PICTURE + "(" + COLUMN_PIC_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_PIC_URL
                + " text not null, " + COLUMN_PIC_LATITUDE + " double, "
                + COLUMN_PIC_LONGITUDE + " double, " + COLUMN_PIC_TIME
                + " text, " + COLUMN_PIC_ACCURACY + " text not null" + ");";

        // Database creation sql statement for accelerometer
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_ACCELEROMETER = "create table "
                + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER
                + "("
                + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_X
                + " float not null, "
                + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Y
                + " float not null, "
                + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_Z
                + " float not null, "
                + COLUMN_ACCELEROMETER_TIME + " text not null" + ");";

        // Database creation sql statement for amplitude
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_AMPLITUDE = "create table "
                + TABLE_AMPLITUDE + "(" + COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_AMPLITUDE + " double not null, "
                + COLUMN_AMPLITUDE_TIME + " text not null" + ");";

        // Database creation sql statement for battery
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_BATTERY = "create table "
                + TABLE_BATTERY + "(" + COLUMN_BATTERY_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_STATUS + " integer not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_ISCHARGING + " integer not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_CHARGEPLUG + " integet not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_USBCHARGE + " integer not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_ACCHARGE + " integer not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_LEVEL + " integer not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_SCALE + " integer not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_BATTERYPCT + " float not null,  "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_TIME + " text not null" + ");";

        // Database creation sql statement for orientation
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_ORIENTATION = "create table "
                + TABLE_ORIENTATION
                + "("
                + COLUMN_ORIENTATION_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_ORIENTATION_AZIMUT
                + " float not null, "
                + COLUMN_BATTERY_TIME + " text not null" + ");";

        // Database creation sql statement for light
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_LIGHT = "create table "
                + TABLE_LIGHT + "(" + COLUMN_LIGHT_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COLUMN_LIGHT_LUMINOSITY + " float not null, "
                + COLUMN_LIGHT_TIME + " text not null" + ");";

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_LOC);
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_PIC);
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_ACCELEROMETER);
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_AMPLITUDE);
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_BATTERY);
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_ORIENTATION);
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_LIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATION);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PICTURE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AMPLITUDE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BATTERY);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORIENTATION);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LIGHT);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case LOCATION:
            qb.setTables(LOCATION_TABLE_NAME);
            //qb.setProjectionMap(dataProjectionMap);
            break;
        case LOCATION_ID:
            selection = selection + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case PICTURE:
            qb.setTables(PICTURE_TABLE_NAME);
            //qb.setProjectionMap(dataProjectionMap);
            break;
        case PICTURE_ID:
            selection = selection + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case ACCELEROMETER:
            qb.setTables(ACCELEROMETER_TABLE_NAME);
            //qb.setProjectionMap(dataProjectionMap);
            break;
        case ACCELEROMETER_ID:
            selection = selection + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case SOUND:
            qb.setTables(SOUND_TABLE_NAME);
            //qb.setProjectionMap(dataProjectionMap);
            break;
        case SOUND_ID:
            selection = selection + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case BATTERY:
            qb.setTables(BATTERY_TABLE_NAME);
            //qb.setProjectionMap(dataProjectionMap);
            break;
        case BATTERY_ID:
            selection = selection + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case ORIENTATION:
            qb.setTables(ORIENTATION_TABLE_NAME);
            //qb.setProjectionMap(dataProjectionMap);
            break;
        case ORIENTATION_ID:
            selection = selection + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case LIGHT:
            qb.setTables(LIGHT_TABLE_NAME);
            //qb.setProjectionMap(dataProjectionMap);
            break;
        case LIGHT_ID:
            selection = selection + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,
                null, sortOrder);

        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        /*switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case LOCATION:
            return Notes.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case PICTURE:
            return Notes.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case ACCELEROMETER:
            return Notes.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case SOUND:
            return Notes.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case BATTERY:
            return Notes.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case ORIENTATION:
            return Notes.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case LIGHT:
            return Notes.CONTENT_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }*/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
        if (sUriMatcher.match(uri) != LOCATION
                || sUriMatcher.match(uri) != PICTURE
                || sUriMatcher.match(uri) != ACCELEROMETER
                || sUriMatcher.match(uri) != SOUND
                || sUriMatcher.match(uri) != BATTERY
                || sUriMatcher.match(uri) != ORIENTATION
                || sUriMatcher.match(uri) != LIGHT) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        ContentValues values;
        if (initialValues != null) {
            values = new ContentValues(initialValues);
        } else {
            values = new ContentValues();
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long rowId = 0;
        Uri _uri = null;

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case LOCATION:
            rowId = db.insert(LOCATION_TABLE_NAME, null/*Notes.TEXT*/, values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_LOCATION, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);

            }
            break;
        case PICTURE:
            rowId = db.insert(PICTURE_TABLE_NAME, null/*Notes.TEXT*/, values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_PICTURE, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);

            }
            break;
        case ACCELEROMETER:
            rowId = db.insert(ACCELEROMETER_TABLE_NAME, null/*Notes.TEXT*/, values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_ACCELEROMETER, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);

            }
            break;
        case SOUND:
            rowId = db.insert(SOUND_TABLE_NAME, null/*Notes.TEXT*/, values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_SOUND, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);

            }
            break;
        case BATTERY:
            rowId = db.insert(BATTERY_TABLE_NAME, null/*Notes.TEXT*/, values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_BATTERY, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);

            }
            break;
        case ORIENTATION:
            rowId = db.insert(ORIENTATION_TABLE_NAME, null/*Notes.TEXT*/, values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_ORIENTATION, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);

            }
            break;
        case LIGHT:
            rowId = db.insert(LIGHT_TABLE_NAME, null/*Notes.TEXT*/, values);
            if (rowId > 0) {
                _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI_LIGHT, rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);

            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
        }
        return _uri;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int count = 0;

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case LOCATION:
            count = db.delete(LOCATION_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case LOCATION_ID:
            where = where + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case PICTURE:
            count = db.delete(PICTURE_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case PICTURE_ID:
            where = where + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case ACCELEROMETER:
            count = db.delete(ACCELEROMETER_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case ACCELEROMETER_ID:
            where = where + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case SOUND:
            count = db.delete(SOUND_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case SOUND_ID:
            where = where + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case BATTERY:
            count = db.delete(BATTERY_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case BATTERY_ID:
            where = where + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case ORIENTATION:
            count = db.delete(ORIENTATION_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case ORIENTATION_ID:
            where = where + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
        case LIGHT:
            count = db.delete(LIGHT_TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case LIGHT_ID:
            where = where + "_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }


        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,
            String[] whereArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int count;
        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case LOCATION:
            count = db.update(LOCATION_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case PICTURE:
            count = db.update(PICTURE_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case ACCELEROMETER:
            count = db.update(ACCELEROMETER_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case SOUND:
            count = db.update(SOUND_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case BATTERY:
            count = db.update(BATTERY_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case ORIENTATION:
            count = db.update(ORIENTATION_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        case LIGHT:
            count = db.update(LIGHT_TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

I think this is going to be done in the `onPerformSync` method of the `syncadapter.java` class

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    // ...
    // Global variables
    // Define a variable to contain a content resolver instance
    ContentResolver mContentResolver;

    /**
     * Set up the sync adapter
     */
    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
        /*
         * If your app uses a content resolver, get an instance of it from the
         * incoming Context
         */
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    }

    // ...
    /**
     * Set up the sync adapter. This form of the constructor maintains
     * compatibility with Android 3.0 and later platform versions
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize,
            boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
        super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);
        /*
         * If your app uses a content resolver, get an instance of it from the
         * incoming Context
         */
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        // ...
    }

    /*
     * Specify the code you want to run in the sync adapter. The entire sync
     * adapter runs in a background thread, so you don't have to set up your own
     * background processing.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
            ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        /*
         * Put the data transfer code here.
         */
        // ...

    }
}
```

But how can i *listen* to what the `contentProvider` has inside it to know in this `onPerformSync` method that it changed and send the data that changed? I can already send the data types i have stored inside the `contentprovider` to a web server. i just need to *listen* to it.

Comment: add `dirty` and `tombstone` column  to each table if you are inserting/upating/deleting from not sync code then set `dirty` flag in the row next in the sync code take the rows with `dirty` flag post to cloud/server then set this flag to false ... when deleting do not delete set `dirty` and `tombstone` flag(remeber that contentProvider.query should return data without those rows) ... in sync code send deleted id to server and delete from sqlite for real ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not a big deal now i understand i only need to perform

contentProvider.onRequestSync and the SyncService from the Sync framework will detect it and call onPerformSync in SyncAdapter